# Python min value in nested lists

Tags: python

```
a_list = [['2', 0.5],
['2', 0.5],
['2', 1.0],
['1', 2.0],
['1', 3.5],
['1', 2.5]]

b_list = {'1', '2'}
```

What is the most pythonic way of calculating the min value from a_list for each value in b_list?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Do you mean value in b_list as index in a_list?

Comment: @Ashish no, i mean, for every i in b_list which is also in a_list, what is the min? So for 1, it'd be 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by preprocessing `a_list` into something that can quickly access all values associated with an element from `b_list`.

```
import collections
a_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in a_list:
    a_dict[k].append(v)

# a_dict = {'1': [2.0, 3.5, 2.5], '2': [.5, .5, 1]}
# If you want to eliminate duplicate values, such as seen
# with the key '2', use a set instead of a list during the aggregation.
```

Now it's just a matter of applying `min` to each appropriate value in `a_dict`

```
for b in b_list:
    print(min(a_dict[b]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the format of the a_list to something else. If that's not easier, then here's the way to do it in numpy.

```
np.min(np.vstack(a_list)[np.where(list(np.vstack(a_list)[:,0]=='1')[0]].astype(float), axis=0)
```